QuickSort implementation (inclusion vs exclusion a pivot element during partition)
I am trying to figure out the QuickSort algorithm. I have tried different implementations. The problem I have relates to the inclusion/exclusion of a pivot element.
Consider these three implementations.

This code would cause an error in VS code and VS code just stops. Notice that the pivot element (ind) is included only once in left (at least it seems this way to me) and it is not added separately in the last line of the function:
def quick_sort(arr):
    if len(arr)<=1:
        return arr
    ind = arr[0]
    left = [i for i in arr if i <= ind]           
    right = [i for i in arr if i > ind]     
    return quick_sort(left) + quick_sort(right)    


If I exclude ind from left (using < instead of <=) and I add [ind] in the last line, it works. BUT the sorted list won't have any duplicates from the original list:
numbers = [5, 2, 3, 2, 7]
print("Sum of numbers:", quick_sort(numbers))

def quick_sort(arr):
    if len(arr)<=1:
        return arr
    ind = arr[0]
    left = [i for i in arr if i < ind]          
    right = [i for i in arr if i > ind]     
    return quick_sort(left) + [ind] + quick_sort(right)    


Finally, this implementation works just fine sorting all values properly. BUT I don't understand what's the difference between this implementation and the first one. Why the first one causes an error, while this one works? Yet in both cases we include the pivot (ind) just once?
numbers = [5, 2, 3, 2, 7]
print("Sum of numbers:", quick_sort(numbers))

def quick_sort(arr):
    if len(arr)<=1:
        return arr
    ind = arr[0]
    left = [i for i in arr if i < ind]  
    middle = [i for i in arr if i == ind]         
    right = [i for i in arr if i > ind]     
    return quick_sort(left) + middle + quick_sort(right) 



I checked the previous Q&A on this topic, but didn't find anything on this problem.

In version #1, if the pivot happens to be the highest value in the list, then left ends up holding EVERYTHING, and you call quick_sort() with exactly the same list as before - which of course does the same thing again, so you have infinite recursion.  For recursion to work, each call has to be strictly closer to a base (non-recursive) case.

Thank you for you response! The problem was that to me #1 and 3 looked the same because both include the pivot element. But apparently I was missing that the stage we include that element matters, so in #1 we passing left+pivot to the recursive call while in #3 we avoid it and add the pivot element on a later stage if needed.

Implementation #1 will suffer from infinite recursion when left takes all values in the given list (and right remains empty). In that case there is no progress and the recursive call will solve the exact same problem again, leading to the same repeated recursive call...etc. This happens for instance with input [2, 1].
You already correctly identified the problem with the second implementation. If the pivot value has duplicates, they are removed from the result. This problem is solved by the third implementation.
Both the second and third implementation solve the problem that the first implementation has: it is guaranteed that the recursive calls will deal with strictly shorter lists, because it is guaranteed that one or all pivot value(s) are no longer member of the list that is passed to the recursive call.
Unrelated to your question, but quicksort is commonly implemented as an inplace algorithm, i.e. without the creation of new lists during the process. Instead the given list is mutated through swaps. See Wikipedia on Quicksort.

Thank you for your quick response! Let me please clarify. Does it mean that in #3 we necessarily exclude the pivot element from the left list and then separately add it on later stage of the algorithm in case some elements are equal to it? In this case we include the pivot element but avoid using it on the recursion stage. Is that correct?

Yes, that is correct. In #3, both left and right are guaranteed to be shorter than arr, because we set the pivot value occurrences aside (they are not included in either left or right) to be added in between the two sorted results we get from recursion.

Thank you again, it was very helpful! I thought I understood it but then I thought that if we choose the middle element as a pivot (len(arr)//2) and then include it in left (using <=) it'll go to infinite recursion again. But in this case subarray gets divided with the each call and hence gets smaller even if we included the pivot. How so then? I am confused

"But in this case subarray gets ... smaller": you still risk that the selected pivot (from the middle) is the greatest value in the array. It doesn't matter where you take your pivot from, if there is a risk it is the greatest value, then you still risk that all values in the array go into the left partition. The trivial example is when you have arr=[1,1,1,1,1,1]. It doesn't matter which 1 you take as pivot (from the middle, or from the left, or ...), you'll always populate left with all of these values.

Thank you so much again, I figured it based on your earlier response. This time I missed that during partition if all the numbers in the subarray are less or equal to the pivot not only the numbers wouldn't change and go to the left part, but the ORDER would stay the same, so the middle element will also stay the same. Now it's clear that it'll stuck in the infinite recursion. I hope this time my understanding is final :) Your response's been very helpful.
